# How do I replace the last character of the selected regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I want this string `{Rotation:[45f,90f],lvl:10s}` to turn into `{Rotation:[45,90],lvl:10}`.

I've tried this:

```
const bar = `{Rotation:[45f,90f],lvl:10s}`
const regex = /(\d)\w+/g
console.log(bar.replace(regex, '$&'.substring(0, -1)))
```

I've also tried to just select the letter at the end using `$` but I can't seem to get it right.

Comment: It would probably be `bar.replace(/(\d+)[a-z]\b/gi, '$1')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
bar.replace(/(\d+)[a-z]\b/gi, '$1')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QhmoOY/1).
Here,

- `(\d+)` - captures one or more digits into Group 1
- `[a-z]` - matches any letter
- `\b` - at the word boundary, ie. at the end of the word
- `gi` - all occurrences, case insensitive

The replacement is Group 1 value, `$1`.

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
const bar = `{Rotation:[45f,90f],lvl:10s}`
const regex = /(\d+)[a-z]\b/gi
console.log(bar.replace(regex, '$1'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The following regex will match each group of one or more digits followed by `f` or `s`.

`$1` represents the contents captured by the capture group `(\d)`.

```js
const bar = `{Rotation:[45f,90f],lvl:10s}`
const regex = /(\d+)[fs]/g
console.log(bar.replace(regex, '$1'))
```

Comment: Tthis only works for the letters f and s does it not?

Comment: @Trojo Yes, please update your question if you have more detailed criteria. Obviously, you can use `[a-z]` if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out :

```
const str = `{Rotation:[45f,90f],lvl:10s}`.split('');
const x = str.splice(str.length - 2, 1)
console.log(str.join(''));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use positive lookahead to match the closing brace, but not capture it.  Then the single character can be replaced with a blank string.

```
const bar= '{Rotation:[45f,90f],lvl:10s}'
const regex = /.(?=})/g
console.log(bar.replace(regex, ''))
{Rotation:[45f,90f],lvl:10}
```